# Reload page when clicking on same url without hash

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've setup ui router this way:

```
  $stateProvider
  .state 'home',
    url: '/'
    template: JST['angular/templates/user/dashboard']
    controller: 'userDashboardCtrl'
  .state 'home.list',
    url: 'list'
    views:
      'content':
        template: JST['angular/templates/user/imageList']
        controller: 'imageListCtrl'
        resolve:
          favoriteOnly: -> false
  .state 'home.favorite',
    url: 'favorite'
    views:
      'content':
        template: JST['angular/templates/user/imageList']
        controller: 'imageListCtrl'
        resolve:
          favoriteOnly: -> true
```

and I ended up having an url like `/users/dashboard#/list`, now I have this link in page:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/users/dashboard">&nbsp;</a>
```

however clicking on that link doesn't reload the page, it just removes the hashes which gets reset by ui-router.

Is there a way to make the browser reload the page as when I remove manually the hash and press return?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Surely the better user experience is for the user not to have to wait for a full page reload?

Comment: Since in some cases the page contents change and with the link I think users expect to return to the initial state otherwise I should map every content change with different urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to refresh a page using `$window.reload()` (you will need to inject `$window` into your controller).

In general, though, it's bad practise for your app to be in a different state if you just refresh the page. Angular apps are meant to be single page web applications. They should have just **one** full page load, and the URL should represent the app's state (to some reasonable resolution).

As such, instead of trying to reload the page, you should consider how your app can reset itself to what the user would expect **without** this page refresh.